# Seaborn: plotting index value in countplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have a dataframe called df_summary:

```
Grouping    High    Low
App_ID      
1   30.813124   69.186876
3   44.444444   55.555556
4   23.873122   76.126878
5   50.000000   50.000000
6   14.353612   85.646388
7   13.333333   86.666667
8   18.895966   81.104034
9   12.745098   87.254902
12  0.000000    100.000000
13  43.788820   56.211180
14  30.147059   69.852941
15  45.714286   54.285714
16  33.635729   66.364271
17  73.076923   26.923077
18  0.000000    100.000000
20  38.775510   61.224490
```

I want to plot it using countplot of seaborn. My code is :

```
sns.countplot(data=df_summary,x='App_ID',hue='Grouping')
```

However, I get an error message of

```
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'App_ID'
```

Looking for your help to rectify the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: the strings you supply to the arguments need to be *column names* of your dataframe. `"App_ID"` is the index, not a column. What's more important though is that `"Grouping"` doesn't even exist. So you would first need to `melt` your dataframe, then reset its index.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried melt. App_ID values disappeared.

Comment: The question is a bit, what are you trying to plot in the end. A countplot of the index is pretty useless, because each index appears exactly twice, so you would get a bar chart with all bars reaching 2.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want to plot the App_ID on x-axis by using Grouping as parameter of hue command.

Comment: That would give you a plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGM1M.png). As said, I don't think that makes much sense.

Answer (score 0):

To do countplots on index of the dataframe, we can use:

```
sns.countplot(x=df_summary['App_ID'])
```

This would interpret your index as input and color of columns would be different based on your index.